# Get values from input when it is array - Laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, input

I'm trying to get values from input that is array in Laravel 4 with:
`$corporate_document = Input::get('corporate_document');`

but it returns NULL.

When I dump Input::all(), it is there:

```html
    array(78) {
    //other inputs
    ["corporate_document"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
          ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          bool(false)
          ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          string(21) "image1.png"
          ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          string(9) "image/png"
          ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          int(46602)
          ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          int(0)
          ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
          string(14) "/tmp/phpmY7ww1"
          ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
          string(9) "phpmY7ww1"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#10 (7) {
          ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          bool(false)
          ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          string(28) "image2.png"
          ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          string(9) "image/png"
          ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          int(46602)
          ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
          int(0)
          ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
          string(14) "/tmp/phpdT87Cm"
          ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
          string(9) "phpdT87Cm"
        }
       
      }
    }
```

How to get values from input `corporate_document` using Input::get() or something like that?

Comment: Are you using laravel 5 or 4, you mention both in your post and i can't figure it out. It looks like you're trying to access $_FILES. You might need to use this code instead https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regular input array, this is an array of files and files are treated differently. You can't access an uploaded file the way you access other request data.

You can try:

```
Input::allFiles(); // See a list of all files
Input::hasFile('corporate_document'); // See if a file exists
Input::file('corporate_document')->move($path); // Rename the file
```

My only concern here is that your `corporate_document` is an array - I'm not sure yet how to address it in this case, but allFiles() may give you the answer. Perhaps it will become something like `Input::file('corporate_document.0');`

Also note that Input facade is just an accessor to Request class (well, in Laravel 5) - so you can run all [the same methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files).

If you are on Laravel 4 - the API should be the same.